# CSS Transitions and IE10

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I understand that IE10 is supposed to support all CSS3 transitions without any kind of vendor prefix. I'm having trouble getting my particular style to display correctly in IE10 though.

Here's an example of my issue: http://jsfiddle.net/ntwiles/8xw5N/1/

```
.photo_bar_image {
    background-image:url("http://i.imgur.com/eODa6AC.jpg");
    border-radius:9px;
    background-size: 125px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 125px;
    height: 125px;
    text-decoration:none;
    transition-property: background-size, background-position;
    transition-duration:0.2s;
}
.photo_bar_image:hover {
    background-size:140px;
    background-position: -5px -5px;
}
```

It works fine in the browsers I've tested, but in IE10, the transition is jumpy. (Specifically, it seems to transition the background-position property correctly, but skip the transition frames of the background-size property.

What kind of options do I have to deal with this kind of issue?

Comment: You can try with `scale`, but it's jumpy on Chrome (Ubuntu). [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/mh2aW/) the fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

try to do like this :

```
.photo_bar_image {
    background-image:url("http://i.imgur.com/eODa6AC.jpg");
    border-radius:9px;
    background-size: 125px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 125px;
    height: 125px;
    text-decoration:none;
    -webkit-transition-property: background-size, background-position;
    -moz-transition-property: background-size, background-position;
     -ms-transition-property: background-size, background-position;
      -o-transition-property: background-size, background-position;
         transition-property: background-size, background-position;
    -webkit-transition-duration:0.2s;
       -moz-transition-duration:0.2s;
        -ms-transition-duration:0.2s;
         -o-transition-duration:0.2s;
            transition-duration:0.2s;
}
.photo_bar_image:hover {
    background-size:140px;
    background-position: -5px -5px;
}
```